# Setting textbox1.text to textbox2.text by using Dependency property in C# silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0

Hi
   I am trying to develop a code to perform a task in Silverlight using Dependency property.

Question:

There are two textboxes, if i entered text in one text box means, the text that is entered in first textbox should also displayed in the second textbox.

If anybody knows please sent me the code.

Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=Text}"/>
```